# Webparts in Blackberry

Tags: iphone, blackberry, mobile

So far I have been creating Web Portal but recently I had a request to convert all the stuff into Mobile Portal.

I have created two webparts, when I place single or multiple webparts of same type it looks fine but when I place two different webparts then its UI gets distracted and it looks bad in Blackberry :(

The UI is fine with IE FireFox and MobileOne(simulator for Iphone), this problem is only with BlackBerry.

Any Idea?? I am using traditional .NET controls and framework to create Mobile Portal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All three of the browsers you mention have a much fuller set of functionality than the BlackBerry Mobile Browser.

For the best results while targetting the BlackBerry Browser, you need to make sure your WebPart page and the WebParts in it are using very basic HTML Markup. This is one of the situations where you're still better off using tables for layouts rather than CSS.

As long as the rendered HTML is simple, the BlackBerry browsser should be able to handle it fairly well.

Answer (score 0):

You should look that mobile controls are rendering pages in xHTML MP. What are you detecting mobile device? If you are using tradicional browsercaps, then you should up date with [mdbf](http://mdbf.codeplex.com/.).

Maybe you could use WURFL ([Marg.WURFL](http://www.mihavalencic.com/wurflapi/) for .NET) what it replace Mobile Capabilities for WURFL Capabilities.